# Need samples "setThreadCount" and "setSuiteThreadPoolSize" methods in TestNG and Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, testng

As I'm learning TestNG framework with parallel testing in selenium tests, I don't understand purpose of the **setThreadCount** and **setSuiteThreadPoolSize** methods that means I can't see the difference in the result.

I may be wrong so can anyone please provide simple program for understanding the uses of these two methods?

Thanks 
Karunagara Pandi

Comment: Can you share your code trials please?

Comment: myTestNG.setXmlSuites(mySuites); 
myTestNG.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(3);
myTestNG.setThreadCount(3);

Comment: They are different means of executing tests in parallel. suitethreadpoolsize is used for running multiple suites ie. different testng.xml in parallel. threadcount is used for specifying how many threads to be used for parallel execution at the suite level. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply...is there any way to determine practically like with simple code ?

Comment: As per the theory, able to understand but when it comes to practical / real time work,  not able to determine how these methods are working. So if any one guide me with the samples, will be helpful for me.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setThreadCount is for setting maximum number of *test classes* to run concurrently in a testNGxml.

setSuiteThreadPoolSize is for setting maximum number of *testNGxmls* to execute of a testNG object. This count is applicable when a testNG runner executes more than 1 xml.

Both the methods are part of **TestNG** class object.